# Getting error for not having node installed yet it is installed

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, .net-core, single-page-application

Error occuring when trying to run spa app with dotnet core backend and react frontend running in Visual Studios on mac OS.
This appears to be a Visual Studios error

This is the error

```
Error: Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE.
```

This is the relevant portion of the csproj file

```
<Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
  </Target>
```

this line specifically is throwing the error

```
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
```

When I type
`node --version` I get `v15.5.0`

Furthermore, when I run the app in command line with `dotnet run` the app runs perfectly fine. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was likely caused by me recently upgrading Mac OS to Big Sur 11.1. All I needed to do was update VS and that fixed this error.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Doing a `dotnet run` from the project folder fixed it for me also in the IDE. No need to update VS.